# How can I apply a Top-to-Bottom layout on a Visio flowchart?

Tags: visual-studio, office-interop, visio

I understand that I can use the following code to layout shapes and links in Visio:

```
VISIO.ActivePage.PageSheet.Layout()
```

This will lay it out in the standard arrangement. I want it to layout such that it is in top-to-bottom arrangement (Where the flowchart would start at the bottom and go down). Any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Visio.ActiveWindow.Page.PageSheet.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowPageLayout, visPLOPlaceStyle).FormulaForceU = "1"
    Visio.ActiveWindow.Page.Layout
```